# Debugging of an Azure Function function app with Maven and IntelliJ-IDEA

Tags: java, spring, azure, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm developing an application for a personal project based on Spring with the use of Azure fuction and CosmosDB. I'm struggling a lot because I can't configure in any possible way a debugger on IntelliJ CE. I've read every single article on internet, tried everything but I keep having always different errors. So, can any of you guys gently give point by point what are the steps to configure this debugger?

Thanks a lot for all the future answers!!

Answer (score 0):

- Create **CosmosDB trigger** Azure function:

[image]

- Click on the **Run** icon in function class (eg: cosmosfunction.java)=> Select **Debug "Run Functions"**
- Then the debug process will be started.. you can check in **Debugger/Console** if the connection is done successfully or not.

[image]

- Upload any **Json file** in your `CosmosDB=>Container=>Items`:

[image]

Go to `IntelliJ=>Debugger` and you can see the debug session started and the actions `Step Over, Step Into, Step Out and Run to Cursor`:

[image]

You can debug the function by clicking on `Step into`:

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

**References:**

[Debug the project locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij#debug-the-project-locally)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it:

1. Make a Maven run configuration that runs your app normally.    The maven command should be: `package azure-functions:run -DenableDebug`
   when that starts, it quietly listens on port 5005 (you don't need to run this one with the debug button in intellij. the regular run button will work)
2. Make another run configuration called Remote, and attach it to the running service.   So, in intellij Idea, you'll have 2 run configs running.   Click the "Debug" button on this config.
   The "Remote" run config will stop on your breakpoints.

Also, I've seen it work where after your app starts, you'll see a hyperlink that says `"connect to Debugger 5005"` in the terminal console right as the function starts.  If you click that link it automatically starts #2 for you.

It's pretty silly that NOBODY can explain this.  If you Google it, you'll get wierd run-arounds by everyone trying to explain it.